# Taking a picture and markers from a DB and display them in a marker custom infowindow

Tags: java, android, postgresql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am stuck and I'll be brief in explaining my problem.

I take multiple markers from a database and I display them on my GoogleMap. I have created custom infowindows for every marker displaying a:
-picture I take from the database and B64 decode it.
-latitude and longitude I also take from the database.

However.. I do not have any clue how to display information for each marker saved in the database. Of course, I can use a snippet for the lat and long and display it on the save line and save me the hassle but for what need? I want to learn how to do that.

My code for the markers method looks like:

```
public void markers() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String sql = "SELECT id, poza, ST_x(geom) AS x, ST_y(geom) AS y, tip_retea AS tr FROM modul";

        PreparedStatement prepst;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            prepst = operations.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = prepst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                final String poza = rs.getString("poza");
                final double longitude = rs.getDouble("x");
                final double latitude = rs.getDouble("y");
                String tip_retea = rs.getString("tr");

                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                String info = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: "
                        + longitude;
                Log.e(Harta.class.getName(), "" + poza.length());

                if (tip_retea.equals("red")) {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latlng)
                            .title("Marker " + id)
                            .snippet(info)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                } else if (tip_retea.equals("green")) {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latlng)
                            .title("Marker " + id)
                            .snippet(info)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                }

                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                            marker.hideInfoWindow();
                            marker.showInfoWindow();
                        }

                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        // Getting view from the layout file
                        // info_window_layout
                        View popUp = inflater
                                .inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

                        latcoord = (TextView) popUp
                                .findViewById(R.id.latinfocont);
                        lngcoord = (TextView) popUp
                                .findViewById(R.id.lnginfocont);
                        title = (TextView) popUp.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        iv = (ImageView) popUp.findViewById(R.id.imageviewinfo);

                        title.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        latcoord.setText(latitude + "");
                        lngcoord.setText(longitude + "");

                        // Load the image thumbnail
                        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64
                                .decode(poza));
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                                140, 160, false));

                        return popUp;

                    }

                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Harta.class.getName(), "query failed to execute: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Basically, I have two type of markers (red and green) and when I click one of them, I want to take the picture and the coordinates from a postgresql database. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a Hashmap to store your variables inside a marker.
In your case:

```
private Map<Marker, String> infowindow = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
```

Declare it as global and in your addMarker method store your variables like:

```
infowindow.put(marker, poza);
```

And finally, in your getInfoContents, do:

```
String picture = infowindow.get(marker);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(picture));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 140, 160, false));
```

For the latitude and longitude, I'll let you figure that out, good luck. :)